# How do I loop my pythagorean theorem program?

Tags: c, loops

Hey, 
I made this program that could execute the pythagorean theorem.
Every time I try to make it loop I get an error saying that nested functions are disabled.
Can one of you tell me how I can make this program loops. Thanks.

This is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float function (float x, float y);
float function2 (float x, float z);
float function3 (float y, float z);

float main()

{
        float x;
        float y;
        float z; 

{
    printf("---------------------------------------------------------------");
    getchar();

    printf("Welcome to right triangle side length calculator");
    getchar();

    printf("If you do not know the legth of the side, enter 0");
    getchar();

    printf("Please insert length of the first leg: ");
    scanf("%f", &x); 

    printf("Please insert length of the second leg: ");
    scanf("%f", &y); 

    printf("Please insert length of the hypotenuse: ");
    scanf("%f", &z);


}

{

    if (z==0){
        printf("The length of the hypotenuse is %f\n",  function (x, y));}


    else if (y==0){ 
        printf("The length of the second leg is %f\n",  function2(x, z));} 


    else if (x==0){
        printf("The length of the first leg is %f\n",  function3(y, z));}


}

printf(" - A Laszlo Solutions Program -\n");

printf("---------------------------------------------------------------");
getchar();

    }



    float function(float x, float y) {

return(sqrt(((x*x)+(y*y))));

    }

    float function2(float x, float z) {

return(sqrt(((z*z)-(x*x))));

    }

    float function3(float y, float z){

return(sqrt(((z*z)-(y*y))));

    }
```

Comment: Using control flow statements like `for`.

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't know what to tell you. Perhaps get yourself a decent book about C to learn the basic constructs of that language.

Comment: Indent your code in a standard way and more people might be willing to look at it. I notice that you have braces in main() that serve no useful purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the definitions of `function1`, `function2` and `function3` outside `main`.

(Your code contains no loops, nested or otherwise. I wonder whether you are misunderstanding the word "loop", which refers to having the same code executed repeatedly.)

Comment: Yea this is the program without any loops in it. I want someone to show me how to do it.

Comment: As Margus says, if you want to make it loop then you need to use a looping construct like `while` or `for`. The problem you've reported doesn't have anything to do with loops. If you're having some separate trouble with looping, perhaps you could clarify what you've tried, what you hoped would happen, and what actually happened instead.

Answer (score 1):

There are Some Problems in your code

**1.**  Return Type of main

```
float main()
{


   return 0.0;  //missing return statement
}
```

**2.**   Check braces

```
float main()
{

   {
         //some statements
   }

   {
         //some statements
   }
}
```

**3.** Unnecessary Functions

```
float function1(float x, float y) 
{

   return(sqrt(((x*x)+(y*y))));        // since, three functions are doing same
                                       // You can use only a function
}
```